# how to disable RemoteApp sessions lock if idle for 10 minutes and require no user needs to input password to unlock?

Tags: windows-server-2008, remoteapp

RemoteApp sessions lock if idle for 10 minutes, user needs to input password to unlock.

My users are running an application from Win2008 Terminal server using RemoteApp.

If the application remains idle for 10 minutes it gets "locked" and the user is required to enter username and password to continue using it.

This is VERY VERY annoying as the app usually sits idle for bout 20-30 minutes, used for 1 min... repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it tied to the screensaver settings like it normally is? Have someone connect to a full desktop session on the server and disable the screensaver. I'm guessing those settings still apply to RemoteApp, though I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 2):

There's no RemoteAPP setting that locks the session, so as db2 suggested take a look at the screensaver settings, and possibly the power settings on the server.